# New instance of Kivy widget does not have attributes of kv lang file

Tags: python, kivy

I created a class for a Popup and set the title property in the kv file.

When the popup shows, it does not have the title as in the kv file, but instead shows No Title as if it was never set.

It is exactly the same problem as here, but I do not understand from this link what the problem is or how to make it work:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/751

I understand how to do this using IDs in kv lang, but that only works if the Popup is put as a child widget of the root widget (ex. MainUI). Then I can link an instance of a python class to a widget in the kv file. 
But then the popup displays as part of the root widget. 
What I want to do, is instantiate a new instance of the popNewDB class when the New button is clicked and have this instance use the values such as "title" in the KV file.

Can you please explain how to do this?

Here is my code:

py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class popNewDB(Popup):
    pass

class MainUI(Widget):
    pop = ObjectProperty(popNewDB())

    def showpopup(self):
        self.pop.open()


class VerseReminder(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    VerseReminder().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<popNewDB>
    title: 'Hallo'

<MainUI>
    Label:
        pos: root.center_x - self.width/2,root.center_y + 200
        text: "Quote Reminder"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: None,None
        width: 400
        height: 200
        pos: root.center_x-200,root.center_y-50
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,1
            text: "New..."
            on_press: root.showpopup()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,1
            text: "Open..."
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,1
            text: "Quit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time `pop = ObjectProperty(popNewDB())` is evaluated, the rules haven't been loaded, so only a barebones `Popup` will be created. Instead, you could do this:

```
class MainUI(Widget):
    pop = ObjectProperty()

    def showpopup(self):
        if self.pop is None:
            self.pop = PopNewDB()
        self.pop.open()
```

Here, the first time the button is pressed, a new instance of `PopNewDB` will be created and stored in `self.pop`.
(*NB:* I renamed the Popup subclass to start with a Capital Letter, to be consistent with language standards and kivy expectations)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make it work by just adding a "pop = popNewDB()" under the "showpopup" function instead and removing the ObjectProperty definition directly under the class.    
But then, as I understand, "pop" will only be limited to the "showpopup" function and I would not be able to reference it later - is that correct? Is that why you first created an ObjectProperty in the class instead?